# Can't seem to get an old image off the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm importing an image (that has to come in portrait) onto a canvas object, rotating it (because it's actually landscape) and running some OCR on the base64 from the canvas.  That all works fine.  However when I put a new image onto the canvas, the old one is retained and never replaced.  I've tried clearRect, even gone to the extent of creating a new dom element each time and destroying it when I have everything I need (which is still in the code below) but I just cannot get the first image to clear.

Here's the relevant bit of the code

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {

//CREATE NEW CANVAS ELEMENT
  g = document.createElement('canvas');
  g.setAttribute("id", "thePic");
  g.style.overflow = "visible";

  document.body.appendChild(g);

  const canvas = document.getElementById('thePic'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  make_base();

  function make_base()
  {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = imageURI;

    base_image.onload = function(){
    const uriheight = base_image.naturalHeight;
    const uriwidth = base_image.naturalWidth;
    console.log(uriwidth + " " + uriheight);

    context.canvas.width  = uriheight;
    context.canvas.height = uriheight;

    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

//ROTATE THE IMAGE 90
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.save();
        context.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        context.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
        context.drawImage(base_image,-base_image.width/1.2,-base_image.width/1.2);
        context.restore();

var theCanvas = document.getElementById('thePic');
var rotImg = theCanvas.toDataURL();
var rotImg = rotImg.substring(21);


              textocr.recText(4, rotImg, onSuccess, onFail);
              function onSuccess(recognizedText) {

        var recdata = recognizedText.lines.linetext;
        var blockData = recognizedText.blocks.blocktext;


    context.clearRect(0, 0, 10000,10000);
    base_image = "";
    rotImg = "";
    document.getElementById('thePic').outerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('cgh').innerHTML = "";
  }
}
}
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to not be the canvas at all, it was image caching in a previous function that give the image to the canvas.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to have a squiz.